# Deleting lines from multiple files

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, replace

How do you search and delete a line (not replace) from multiple files in a directory tree? I have tried programs such as grepWin and Windows Grep but they replace lines, they do not delete the entire line. What is my best option?

Example: Search for "hello" and delete any line with "hello" in it.

```
yo
hello hey hey
hi hello
bye 
bye
```

should come back

```
yo
bye
bye
```

Comment: Tagging with language-agnostic since you didnt specify a language. Feel free to change if the language does matter.

Comment: Tagging with windows since you used windows tools. Feel free to change if the platform was a real OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way in grepWin or Windows Grep to do it.

Regex Search:^.*hello.*$\r\n
Regex Replace:

(blank replace)

Comment: Great finding! Thanks to your example, I was able the delete all occurences (complete lines) of the text `.*www.unwantedspamsite.com.*\r\n` anywhere inside my text files with grepWin.

Answer (score 3):

With Powershell positioned in the root directory:

```
foreach($file in (dir -r -i *.txt -force)) { $cleaned = gc $file | where { $_ -notlike "*Hello*" }; sc $file $cleaned }
```

Change the *.txt filter and the "*Hello*" match criteria to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest installing cygwin if you do not already have it - it is full of tools for doing things like this.

You can delete lines with sed:

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' filename...
```

The -i option tells sed to edit the file in-place.  -i.bak will leave a backup file with an extension of .bak.

To process all the files in the directory tree I suggest running the command in zsh.  Zsh has some funky filename expansion options compared to bash, e.g.

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' **/*.(c|h)
```

will run sed on every file from the current directory downwards that has an extension of .c or .h.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, the files have an extension of .foo, the following should do:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /s /b *.foo') do findstr /v hello %f > c:\temp\x && move /y c:\temp\x %f
```

hth - Rene

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -R --revert-match
```

might work. Some GNU grep versions do support recursive search by file mask, but I'm not sure about Windows ports.

More long but easier way,

```
gfind . -name "*.txt" | xargs deleteLine.bat hello
```

where gfind is GNU find from, for instance, unxutils.sf.net, and deleteLine.bat is like:

```
grep %1 --revert-match %2 > tempfile.###
move tempfile.### %2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have cygwin, you can use sed:

```
cat test.txt  | sed 's/.*hello.*//'
```

This will delete lines with hello, but show the blank lines. If you don't like the blan lines, you can do:

```
cat test.txt  | sed 's/.*hello.*//' | sed '/^$/d'
```

Edit: On second thought, the complete thing can be simplified as:

```
sed '/.*hello.*/d' test.txt
```

where test.txt is the file.

Comment: This will also erase all other blank lines.
You can pipe a file into sed with < , not using `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless m/pattern/' file1 file2 file3 ...
```